# Chartjs + Vue.js - Cannot read property '_meta' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I am building an app using Vue.js + Chartjs. I am having a problem where I make a http call to a service to get data, parse it, and pass it into my Chartjs component. However, I keep getting the error `Cannot read property '_meta' of undefined`

Here are the relevant parts of my component:

```
<template>
    <Chartjs :data="chartData" />
</template>

export default {
data () {
    return {
        chartData: false
    }
},
created () {
    this.getData()
},
methods: {
    getData() {
    const opts = {
        url: 'some_url',
        method: 'get'
    }
    request.callRoute(opts).then(results => {
        this.chartData = results.data
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
    }
},
components: {
    Chartjs
}
}
```

Note - the chart renders fine if I hard code the `chartData` field with data that comes back from my request. However, it does NOT work if I make a http request first for my data.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue will render the component with the initial `chartData` (which is a boolean). You should use a v-if or other logic and render `Chartjs` component when you have the response. For example you can show a loading message/animation while the `chartData` is false.